# Grails Domain Design: inheritance or one class with nullable properties?

Tags: grails, inheritance, grails-orm

I have a domain *OrderItem*

```
class OrderItem {
    Product product
    Packaging packaging
    //other details
}

class Product {
 //other details
}

class Packaging {
//other details
}
```

Currently, OrderItem refers only to **Beers**. Product is the type of beers. Packaging is the cans/bottles/keg/etc.

Then the client decides to also sell items that *are not* beers: Spirits, Ingredients, Souvenirs, etc.

I'm thinking that these are all OrderItem objects, but the system currently treats OrderItem as Beers. How should I introduce the expanded models? (Note: Some of the new items don't have product, packaging or both.)

1. **Inheritance**? Still treat OrderItem as Beers only. Then all the new items will have their own class that extends OrderItem. Pros and cons? Table per hierarchy or per class?
2. **Add properties(some are nullable)** to OrderItem to distinguish the new items? Like 'category', 'someItemCode', 'someItemPricing', etc.

Comment: I would say go with second approach, add attributes to OrderITem which says what item is it, what it's code, price etc.. that we you can support new  items easily without having to add a subclass for every new item you may have to support in future.

Comment: If you decide to go with inheritence, use table per class if you don't need polymorphic queries, that is single query to find all order items "sprits, ingredients, souvenirs with price less then 100". If you need polymorphic queries and can live without not null constraints you can go with table per class hierarchy. table per hierarchy would give better performance, table per class would give ability to specify null constraint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer the second one, **adding additional property** like `category` or `itemType`.

So when adding the new field your migration script must set the `itemType` field value to `Beers` for all the existing records( Because all the products you had are all `Beers`).

I dont know which of your fields are going to be `null`, but if your `OrderItem`  table is still having many `nullable` columns you need to to normalize it.